# jQuery works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [jQuery mash menu plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/mash-mega-menu-bootstrap/12141322) and I have a fixed menu on the top of my page, but on responsive my fixed menu is not set to `display:block` itself. After page refresh it's set to `display:block`, but if I remove the plugin or HTML structure of the plugin everything works OK. I guess the problem is with the mash menu plugin but I have to use this plugin.

How does my fixed menu work?

My fixed menu does not appear by default but if I scroll down to reservation page it sets `display:block` on itself. (just responsive <768px)

edit: not just fixed menu - back to top menu doesn't work on mobile

MY JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
       if (!$(".hotel-search-box").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height()){
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeIn(500);
      }else{
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeOut(500);
      }
  });
})
```

MASH PLUGİN JS

```
  $('.mash-menu').mashableMenu({
                separator                      : true,      //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to show the vertical line between menu list items
                ripple_effect                  : false,      //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to on - off the google ripple effect on menu items. Which is shown on mouse click
                search_bar_hide                : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to hide the search bar
                top_fixed                      : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to fixed the menu top of the screen. Note: If this option becomes true then the sticky_header option will not work
                full_width                     : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to make the menu full with
                right_to_left                  : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to align the menu items right to left side order
                trigger                        : 'hover',   //-- Options (click) or (hover). This option is used to showing the drop down on mouse click or mouse hover
                /* VERTICAL TABS */
                vertical_tabs_trigger          : 'click',   // Options (click) or (hover). This option is used to showing the vertical tabs on mouse click or mouse hover
                vertical_tabs_effect_speed     : 400,       // Value in milliseconds. This option is used to change the vertical tabs showing or hiding speed
                /* RESPONSIVE TABS */
                //responsive_tabs_effect_speed   : 200,       // Value in milliseconds. This option is used to change the responsive tabs showing or hiding speed
                /* DROP DOWN */
                drop_down_effect_in_speed      : 200,       // Value in milliseconds. This options is used to change the drop downs showing speed
                drop_down_effect_out_speed     : 200,       // Value in milliseconds. This option is used for change the drop downs hiding speed
                drop_down_effect_in_delay      : 200,       // Value in milliseconds. This option is used to change the drop downs showing delay speed. It means drop down shows after some time
                drop_down_effect_out_delay     : 200,       // Value in milliseconds. This option is used to change the drop downs hiding delay speed. It means drop down hides after some time
                outside_close_dropDown         : true,      // Options (true) or (false). This option is used to hide the showing drop downs when user click outside the menu
                /* STICKY HEADER */
                mobile_search_bar_hide         : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This option is used to hide the search bar on mobile mode
                mobile_sticky_header           : false,     //-- Options (true) or (false). This options is used to make the menu sticky on top of the screen on mobile mode
                mobile_sticky_header_height    : 100,       //-- Value in milliseconds. This option is used to change the sticky header animation effect speed on mobile mode
                /* MEDIA QUERY WIDTH */
                media_query_max_width          : 768       //-- This is media query max width in px unit. Which is Used for mobile screen. Don't change if you don't know about media query
            });
```

[click to demo address](http://nopagefound.html)

edit: if you check out on responsive (<768px) you'll see that nothing happens if you scroll page down, but if you refresh the page and scroll down you'll see it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears only when you resize the browser. If you open the page in <768px it works fine. There is some problem with onresize event.

Comment: are you sure ? open page less than 768px without refresh and try scroll page to down if you gonna see fixed menu has been appear yes you right but nothing happening for me :)

Comment: I just checked it again. If you open the page directly on <768px the up button and fixed menu work when I scroll. What is not happening to you?

Comment: no nothing happend on my dekstop and mobile adn I'm talking about fixed bar which is orange?

Comment: on mobile refresh page and tell me are you gonna see this fixed bar ?

Comment: It works when I open it on my iPhone and desktop when open it directly on < 768px. Up button and orange bar at the top appears when scrolling. It doesn't work only when you open the page on large browser and you don't scroll ant resize. If you scroll before resize - the 2 element are visible. This is what i see :) I won't confirm again :)

Comment: I don't understan I'm trying to be sure it's not work my iphone my desktop and another my friend computer..look first open page and make it responsive without refreshing and you gonna see fixed(orange) not be apper by the way fixed bar must be top of the page like this https://yadi.sk/i/5AR0W8Hhv3AdY please I want to be sure

Comment: You make it responsive while you making it not when resizing :). I see what I told you before, just checked again. Ask other people what they see. Maybe it doesn't work on your comp and phone due to caching?

Comment: I understand thanks I clear my temporary cache and everyhing but same problem continues interesting